# Sending html message via Skype4com

Tags: html, message, send, skype, skype4com

I want to send a message in skype with html tags using skype4com library. How I can do this? Is it impossible?
I tried to send a message to the body  **Hello** , but in Skype it remains the same.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the skype4come library? And now, If your thinking about this, I don't think its yet possible, since Skype has stopped working with API's, Some API's still work with skype as today, but not for sure if you can interact with the skype client to send messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because you can't communicate with Skype anymore via the API :

https://gigaom.com/2013/07/13/skype-says-it-will-kill-desktop-api-by-end-of-2013/

You should now be using URI

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745878(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection0